# extract path from .lnk file in php

Tags: php, codeigniter, symlink

I want to redirect to particular path when click on `shortcut`

How to achieve this?

For ex: `TECH.lnk` if i click on this is it should redirect to `C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\folder\\`

this what i have done:

```
   $link =  'TECH.lnk';
   $res = file_get_contents($link);
   echo '<pre>'; print_r($res);
```

it gives me the following error :

```
The connection was reset
```

Comment: Click on the link or a folder?

Comment: @Abbas : when user click on the `TECH.lnk` it should open the appropriate path of the fodler of file which given in to that symbolic link

Comment: What i understand is, There will be be the links on the web page. Such as TECH.lnk1 and TECH.lnk2 when User will click the TECH.lnk1 then it should open a file like C:\xampp\htdocs\folder\1.txt and  C:\xampp\htdocs\folder\2.txt for TECH.lnk2. Is it right?

Comment: @Abbas : yes correct

Comment: See the answer.

Comment: You need to create .htaccess file for redirecting to target location

Comment: @sunilwananje : can you please elaborate more on this?

Answer (score -1):

```
<html>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function openFile(file){
        window.open(
            file,
            '_blank' // <- This is what makes it open in a new window.
        );
    }
</script>
<body>
    <a href="#" onclick="javascript:openFile('1.txt')">1 Text</a>
    <a href="#" onclick="javascript:openFile('2.txt')">2 Text</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Here i am using the relative path for file you can also use the absolute path rather then relative path. and it will open the file in a new tab. I hope it will work for you. Best of luck.

Comment: Who vote down this post. Can you please explain the reason? Thank you very much.